# Would like to clarify if it is the view did load error or is it the code problem?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, in-app-purchase, segue

Would be kind enough to assist in clarifying the details. I tried to input the in app purchase view controller via segue & dismiss it via user defaults, but the controller does not present & crashes indicating a view did load error. Therefore, would like to clarify if it is the view did load error or is it the code problem??

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    if isPurchased() {
        showDetails()
    }
}

override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

     if segue.identifier == "subscribepage1" {
           buyPremium()
     } else if segue.identifier == "subscribepage2" {
            buyPremium()
     }
}

func isPurchased() -> Bool {
    let purchaseStatus = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productID)
    if purchaseStatus {
        print("Previously purchased")
        return true
    } else { print("Never purchased")
        return false
    }
}

func showDetails() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: productID)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotop1", sender: self)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotop2", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell if you have an error in copying and pasting your code, or your code is wrong. I think it would help you a lot to be more consistent with indenting your code appropriately. To me it looks like you are missing a close bracket after your first function. Get yourself a good IDE and it will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your code only, when your calling showDetails() Method your executing two segues at the same time

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotop1", sender: self)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotop2", sender: self)
```

validate/add condition for these two lines, either "gotop1" or "gotop2".

Comment: Hi Komara, thanks for the advice. I've tried separating them but still unable to connect or make the view controller act as i hope to. What validation or add what to these lines do you suggest?

Comment: I would like to know one thing first,Are u still getting the same error?. If not let me know how u r expecting to work those.

Comment: i was hoping to show a view controller using a segue (in app purchase) then dismiss that view (also adding user defaults). the problem seems to be the view would not load after I click on the button (signet 1 error) was displayed. Thanks for your help Komara:) appreciate it